# Discord.py Bot : Sends with the loverate between 2 persons

Tags: python

I'm creating a Discord Bot and i made a !love command which is testing the love rate between 2 persons or entities.

Example : !love Peignoir Emma

Result: The loverate between Peignoir and Emma is x%

Here's the code :

```
@bot.command(name="love", aliases=["l"])
async def love(ctx, Personne1, Personne2):
    if ctx.message.channel.id != 763352957579690018:
        printIt = 1
        wordBanList = ['@everyone', '@here', '<@&763489250162507809>','<@&777564025432965121>','<@&822200827347075132>',
                       '<@&763815680306184242>','<@&764422266560839680<','<@&763815728972300338>','<@&763815728972300338>',
                       '<@&763815228323528725>','<@&763815784904261632>','<@&764422166116171806>','<@&764422057353936897>',
                       '<@&804807279043674143>','<@&828664814678179861>','<@&823562218095640646>','<@&823638574809219163>']
        LoveRate = str(random.randrange(0, 100))
        for y in range(len(wordBanList)):
            if(Personne1 == wordBanList[y] or Personne2 == wordBanList[y]):
                printIt = 0

        if(printIt == 0):
            await ctx.send("Tu t'es pris pour qui ?")
            if debug == True:
                print("[DEBUG] !love : Someone tried to use a banned word !")
        else:
            await ctx.send("L'amour entre **"+Personne1+"** et **"+Personne2+"** est de **"+LoveRate+"%** <:flushed:830502924479758356>")
            if debug == True:
                print("[DEBUG] !love : The love rate ("+LoveRate+"%) between "+Personne1+" and "+Personne2+" has been printed in channel ID "+str(ctx.channel.id))
    else:
        botChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id=768194273970880533)
        messageBot = await ctx.send("Va faire cette commande dans "+botChannel.mention+" ou je te soulève <:rage:831149184895811614>")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await messageBot.delete()
```

I'm pretty sure this code is optimizable, but i don't know how, can somebody help me :) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Never iterate over indices in python**

In Python this pattern is generally not recommended:

```
for y in range(len(wordBanList)):
    if(Personne1 == wordBanList[y] or Personne2 == wordBanList[y]):
        printIt = 0
```

You almost never need to iterate over and access elements by their indices. Instead you should directly iterate over the elements of the iterable:

```
for word in wordBanList:
    if Personne1 == word or Personne2 == word:
        printIt = 0
```

Also notice that you do not need the parentheses around the `or` statement.

If you do need the index as well you can use built-in `enumerate`:

```
for index, word in enumerate(wordBanList):
    ...
```

---

**Membership tests**

As Harsha pointed out, `set`s are optimized for membership tests, so use them when possible. Doing so can also make your assignment of `printIt` way more concise:

```
wordBanList = {'@everyone', '@here', '<@&763489250162507809>', ...}
printIt = 0 if (Personne1 in wordBanList or Personne2 in wordBanList) else 1
```

Parantheses are also not required here, but might improve readability.

---

**Naming convention**

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names):

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by
> underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.

Variable and function names should follow snake_case.

---

**`debug == True`**

As a general rule of thumb, you should always use `is` with the built-in constants: `True`, `False` and `None`. It might also suffice to check `debug` for truthiness (`if debug:`). This however depends on the use case, since the expressions are not equivalent. The second one will fail for all falsey values, not just `False` (e.g. an empty string, an empty list). If you're interested, you can read more about [Truthy and Falsy Values in Python](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/).

---

**String formatting**

```
LoveRate = str(random.randrange(0, 100))
```

`LoveRate` (or better `love_rate`) should not be of type `str`, since you only need its `str`-represantation to print it. You can let Python handle formatting for you, by using [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). That way you never have to think about casting to `str`.

```
print("[DEBUG] !love : The love rate ("+LoveRate+"%) between "+Personne1+" and "+Personne2+" has been printed in channel ID "+str(ctx.channel.id))
```

becomes

```
print(f"[DEBUG] !love : The love rate ({LoveRate}%) between {Personne1} and {Personne2} has been printed in channel ID {ctx.channel.id}")
```

---

A few other small points:

1. Instead of wrapping the main code inside an `if-else`-block we can use `ctx.message.channel.id == 763352957579690018` as an exit condition.
2. `print_it` is of type `int`, but basically acts as a variable of type `bool`. We can also eliminate that variable entirely, since we only use it once.
3. Line length should ideally not exceed 80 characters. You can use parantheses to conveniently concatenate strings across multiple lines, as described in this [reddit tip](https://www.reddit.com/r/pythontips/comments/4mevao/use_parenthesis_to_wrap_long_strings/). My IDE is set to hard wrap only at 100 characters, so that's the maximum length for the lines below.

```
@bot.command(name="love", aliases=["l"])
async def love(ctx, personne1, personne2):
    if ctx.message.channel.id == 763352957579690018:
        bot_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id=768194273970880533)
        message_bot = await ctx.send(f"Va faire cette commande dans {bot_channel.mention} "
                                     f"ou je te soulève <:rage:831149184895811614>")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await message_bot.delete()
        return

    word_ban_list = {'@everyone', '@here', '<@&763489250162507809>', '<@&777564025432965121>',
                     '<@&822200827347075132>', '<@&763815680306184242>', '<@&764422266560839680<',
                     '<@&763815728972300338>', '<@&763815728972300338>', '<@&763815228323528725>',
                     '<@&763815784904261632>', '<@&764422166116171806>', '<@&764422057353936897>',
                     '<@&804807279043674143>', '<@&828664814678179861>', '<@&823562218095640646>',
                     '<@&823638574809219163>'}

    love_rate = str(random.randrange(0, 100))

    if personne1 in word_ban_list or personne2 in word_ban_list:
        await ctx.send("Tu t'es pris pour qui ?")
        if debug:
            print("[DEBUG] !love : Someone tried to use a banned word !")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"L'amour entre **{personne1}** et **{personne2}** est de **{love_rate}%** "
                       f"<:flushed:830502924479758356>")
        if debug:
            print(f"[DEBUG] !love : The love rate ({love_rate}%) between {personne1} and"
                  f"{personne2} has been printed in channel ID {ctx.channel.id}")
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for your answer, it truly helped me. I'm very happy to have such answers on my first question, Stack Exchange's community is very friendly and helpful ! :) If you wanna check out our project on Github, you can click [here](https://github.com/Firminou/octo-timetable)

Comment: @JSuisEnPeignoir I'd also recommend using `logging` module over those `print` statements.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Alright, i'll check it out, thank you for your help as well ! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
for y in range(len(wordBanList)):
            if(Personne1 == wordBanList[y] or Personne2 == wordBanList[y]):
                printIt = 0
```

This code is checking to see if Personne1 or Personne2 are in wordBanList and has O(len(wordBanList)) runtime time. You can change the data type of your wordBanList to set() and have a O(1) run time. So your code could be transformed to:

```
if Personne1 in wordBanList or Personne2 in wordBanList:
    printIt = 0
```

P.S: If you have a small wordBanList (like <100 words), leaving the wordBanList as a list would not make a HUGE difference compared to sets. But, when there are a lot of words (>10,000,000), the difference is significant. https://towardsdatascience.com/faster-lookups-in-python-1d7503e9cd38